# javascript string replace when string has <br />

Tags: javascript, str-replace

```
notes.replace(/<br />/g,"\r")
```

I have a string with several `<br />` in it.   Replacing the first one with `\r` seems to work fine.  I just can't figure out the syntax for global replaced.   Tried several combinations, does not seem to work.   Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That works? Really? I'm pretty sure you should be escaping the `/` character inside of the regular expression: `/<br \/>/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this you should be able to find any valid `br` Tag: As already said by Utkanos the `?` means that the preceding character is optional in the search pattern. `\s*` means that any amount of spaces are matched.

```
notes.replace(/<br\s*\/?>/g,"\r");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check the console you'll see it errors as the REGEX pattern is invalid. You need to escape the forward slash.

```
/<br ?\/>/g
```

The `?` also means the space is optional, so it will match `<br/>` as well as `<br />`.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
notes.replace(/<br\/>/g,"\r")
```